# Use Socket or webserver?

Tags: android, sockets, embedded

I want to establish communication between set top box and an android phone.
Is it better to use sockets or communicate via an embedded web server ?

Comment: Communicate....What?

Comment: communicate between STB and android phone

Comment: I meant: what type of data do you want to send/receive?

Comment: strings in real time

Comment: if possible json files to have the possibilty to use the web service volley of android

Comment: also verification of login and password

Comment: But a web-server uses sockets.  HTTP is a TCP/IP application layer protocol appropriate to serving HTML content.  What you are really asking is should I use HTTP or a proprietary application layer.  Those of course are not your only choices.

Comment: what do you propose as a solution ?

Comment: there is no right answer, there is no best solution.  why dont you just try both one at a time and see which one you prefer for your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) An embedded web server can operate with any device having a browser, android devices included, with nice graphics/user interface. But it is heavier than solution 2.

2) Sockets is a lighter solution than a web server, but require an app (android) or a program (non-android) that know what to do and implement a user interface.

If the embedded web server is viable, probably is the easier solution.